# Total accumulated risk

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm a big fan of Minesweeper. Like other fans, I know that probabilities are important in this game. So, for more fun, I play on this player : http://mrgris.com/projects/minesweepr/demo/player/.

After sometime, I asked myself what's the meaning of the statistic : total accumulated risk. After checking at the code source, I know that the value of this statistic is calculated like :
$$p_{n+1}=1-(1-p_n)(1-r_n)$$
Let $p_n$ is the total accumulated risk and $r_n$ the risk taken by selected this cell.

(Thanks for @joriki about the corrections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is misleading – read as an equation, it implies $P(C)=1$ or $P(T)=1$, which is most likely not the intended interpretation.

Rather, this is an update prescription, $P(T)\leftarrow1-(1-P(T)(1-P(C))$. Writing this as $p_{n+1}=1-(1-p_n)(1-r_n)$ and rearranging yields $1-p_{n+1}=(1-p_n)(1-r_n)$. Thus, this is a simple multiplicative update of the complements: The risk is the complement of the probability of survival, and the total accumulated probability of survival is the product of the individual probabilities of survival.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. But, when I play, how this statistic represent my game!?

Comment: @hlapointe: Hmm -- I thought that's what I wrote. Maybe it sounds more complicated than it is because of all the complements; I don't know why they prefer to express it in terms of the complements. Think of it in terms of your survival probability -- every time you click on a cell that wasn't known to be mine-free, your survival probability gets multiplied by the probability of that cell being mine-free. The "total accumulated risk" is the complement of that, the probability of death, i.e. how likely it was that you'd have died up to this point in the game by clicking on those risky cells.

Comment: By the way, that's a great site you linked to -- thanks!